# javascript / math - improper rotation of of items around a circle

Tags: javascript, math, geometry, three.js

I'm trying to arrange a series of planes in a circle, "facing" the center, but I'm getting some odd results after I pass 180 degrees. My objects are distributed properly around the circle, but the rotation is off. I've attached a screenshot and my code is below: what's wrong with my equation?

```
var circleRadius = 12;
var diameter = circleRadius*2;
var centerX = -5;
var centerZ = -2.5;

var mpi = Math.PI/180;
var startRadians = startAngle + mpi;
var totalSpheres = 8;
var incrementAngle = 360/totalSpheres;
var incrementRadians = incrementAngle * mpi;

for ( var i = 0; i < totalSpheres; i ++ ) {

    var xp = centerX + Math.sin(startRadians) * circleRadius;
    var zp = centerZ + Math.cos(startRadians) * circleRadius;

    var camObj = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 1*camSize, .75*camSize ), material );

    camObj.position.x = xp;
    camObj.position.z = zp;
    camObj.rotation.y = i*incrementAngle; //MH - do this without degrees
    console.log(camObj.rotation.y);
    startRadians += incrementRadians;

    scene.add( camObj );

}
```

[image: alignment of objects]

Comment: What's the output of your console.log? Did you try `-i*incrementAngle`?

Comment: log produces predictable numbers - 45, 90, 135, 180, etc. Negative i did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could be wrong. Never used the library, but looking at it in github it seems like rotation should be in radians not degrees.

```
var circleRadius = 12;
var diameter = circleRadius*2;
var centerX = -5;
var centerZ = -2.5;

var mpi = Math.PI/180;
var startRadians = startAngle + mpi;
var totalSpheres = 8;
var incrementAngle = 360/totalSpheres;
var incrementRadians = incrementAngle * mpi;

for ( var i = 0; i < totalSpheres; i ++ ) {

    var xp = centerX + Math.sin(startRadians) * circleRadius;
    var zp = centerZ + Math.cos(startRadians) * circleRadius;

    var camObj = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 1*camSize, .75*camSize ), material );

    camObj.position.x = xp;
    camObj.position.z = zp;
    camObj.rotation.y = i*incrementAngle * (Math.PI/180.0); //MH - do this without degrees
    console.log(camObj.rotation.y);
    startRadians += incrementRadians;

    scene.add( camObj );

}
```